# How to determine the dimensions of a mix of lists and arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, list, numpy

Consider an object that is a list of arrays:

`a=[array([1,2,3]),array(2,5,10,20)]`

In its own funny way, this thing has two dimensions. The list itself is one dimension, and it contains objects which are 1D. Is there an easy way to distinguish between `a` above and a list like `b=[1,3,6,9,11]` which is simply 1D, and `c=1`, which is a 0D scalar? I want a function `dimens()` such that `dimens(a)` returns `2`, `dimens(b)` returns `1`, and `dimens(c)` returns `0`.

I am doing it by testing the shape of the first element in the list, but I feel like there may be a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def dimens(l):
    try:
        size = len(l)
    except TypeError: # not an iterable
        return 0
    else:
        if size: # non-empty iterable
            return 1 + max(map(dimens, l))
        else: # empty iterable
            return 1

print(dimens([[1,2,3],[2,5,10,[1,2]]]))
print(dimens(np.zeros([6,5,4,3,2,1])))
```

**Output**

```
3
6
```

Comment: Nice. What sets the limit on the maximum dimensions it will detect? It goes up to 4, which is pretty cool, but I tested it with `zeros([6,5,4,3,2,1])`, which should be 6 dimensional, and it only said 4. Anyway, topping out at 4 is fine for what I'm doing. Thanks.

Comment: The code now works with numpy arrays as well and returns `6` for `zeros([6,5,4,3,2,1])`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my function:

```
def dimens(x):
    s=shape(x)
    if len(s)==0:
        return 0 #the input was a scalar
    s2=shape(x[0])
    if len(s2)==0:
        return 1 #each element of the list was a scalar
    else:
        #each element of the list was a vector or array
        if len(s2)==1:
            if len(shape(s2[0]))==0:
                return 2 #the first element of the top list was a 1D vector and the first element of that vector was a scalar
        return 3 #there were more than 2 dimensions involved
```

Testing:

```
a=[array([1,2,3]),array([2,5,10,20])]
b=[1,3,6,9,11]
c=1
d=[[a]]+[[a]]

print dimens(a)
2
print dimens(b)
1
print dimens(c)
0
print dimens(d)
3
```

Limitations:

- Only goes up to three dimensions (this is enough for my application)
- Only tests the first element, so it assumes that each element has the same dimensionality (which is fine for my application since my 2D case will be a list of all arrays, not a list that has a mix of arrays and scalars)

Can anyone do better?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **isinstance** method to distinguish between the two arrays

Lets consider the first list

```
a = [1,2,3]
```

Here the first element is an integer hence `isinstance(a[0],int)` will return true

For the second array `b = [[1,2][3,4]]` the first element is an array so `isinstance(b[0],int)` will return false. 
You can check the second list by using `isinstance(b[0],list)`

I am using list in place of array but it will work with arrays also